# When you swing a baseball bat in Unity, there are times when you don't hit the ball

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, collider

First, each collider component was added so that the bat could detect the collision of the ball.

However, the OnTriggerEnter function sometimes did not work properly because of the speed of the animation swinging the bat or the speed of the flying ball.(I stopped the ball and set the animation to 0.1, so I made sure it was working properly.)

I don't want to slow down the animation speed or the speed of the ball swinging the bat, so I've been trying several ways and I've changed the Edit -> Project Setting -> Time -> Fixed Timestep to 0.005, which fixed the problem.
[image]

But there was another problem. Since the game I make is a mobile game, I tested it on mobile and the frame came out too low, so I fixed the frame to 60

When the frame was fixed at 60, the bat, which was a good collision, did not collide well again.. I thought this issue was being affected by the frame, so I fixed the frame at 200 and ran it again and found out it was working well.

I've also thought about "boxcast" to solve this problem again, but I don't really know what to do. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Things do not move continuously in games. Instead, their placement skips through space. If two objects approach each other fast enough, they'll skip through each other without touching properly or even at all.

Comment: The issue is that the animation and physics happen on Update and FixedUpdate respectively. They can easily desynchronize or have too big of a step for the animation.
I am going to suggest something cursed. Have your trigger as a separate object that is detached from the animation and has a kinematic rigidbody with continuous collision detection as well as a script that changes the position and rotation every FixedUpdate to match the rotation and position of the bat.